# VSCode extension installation on remote failing due to "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Recently been running into issues updating extension within VS Code on remote systems (Linux - Centos 7).  The error I am encountering appear to be related to certifcates.

```
[2022-08-03 18:11:52.177] [remoteagent] [info] Getting Manifest... ms-vscode.hexeditor
[2022-08-03 18:11:52.839] [remoteagent] [error] Failed to install extension. ms-vscode.hexeditor
[2022-08-03 18:11:52.840] [remoteagent] [error] Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12)
```

On the remote machine I double checked to ensure the company's pem certificate is present in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`.  I verified with IT that the proxy settings are correct and have "http.proxyStrictSSL" set to false.

Are there some logging options that I can enable in VS Code to aid in debugging?  Are there some logs that I can look at under `/var/log/`?

Comment: Keep in mind it may be a bug in the extension. ms-vscode.hexeditor installer code as well.

Comment: This is happening across multiple extension.  This was just the first example I grabbed.

Comment: Try this command `curl -v https://www.microsoft.com` to see if it works.